# Proving that my series-function is continuous

Tags: analysis

I'm going to show that $$f(x) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan(kx)}{k^{2}} $$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

I was thinking that I can show that our series is uniformly convergent. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{\arctan(kx)}{k^{2}} \right|\le \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{2}} $$

Does this imply that it's continuous in $\mathbb{R}$? I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, let define: $$f_n:x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto\frac{\arctan(nx)}{n^2}.$$ 
You have proved that: $$\sum\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)|$$ is convergent. One says that $\displaystyle\sum f_n$ is normally convergent on $\mathbb{R}$, in particular, $\displaystyle\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, since each $f_n$ is continuous, $\displaystyle\sum f_n$ is continuous.

*Remark.* A uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I dont really get why uniform convergence implies continuity.. What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: First, let's see that pointwise convergence of continuous functions does not implies continuity. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let define $f_n:x\in[0,1]\mapsto x^n$, $f_n$ is continuous. However, $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=0$ if $0\leqslant x< 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=1$, if $x=1$. Hence, $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent to $f:x\in[0,1]\mapsto\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0,\textrm{ if }x\neq 1\\1\textrm{, otherwise}\end{array}\right.$, which is not continuous.

Comment: But wait, if x=1 how does the limit equal zero?

Comment: Well seen, let me fixed it.

Comment: Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous function that converges uniformly towards $f$. Let $x_0$ and let $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that: $$\forall x,\forall n\geqslant N,|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$
There exists $\eta$ such that: $$\forall x,y,|x-y|<\eta\Rightarrow|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|<\varepsilon.$$ Hence, using triangular inequality, one has: $$\forall x,|x-x_0|<\eta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant|f(x_0)-f_N(x_0)|+|f_N(x_0)-f_N(x)|+|f_N(x)-f(x)|<3\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence of functions, 
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\arctan(kx)}{k^2},
$$
defined for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If you can show that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ and that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n(x)$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)$ is continuous.

Note: refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence for the definition of uniform convergence.